# How do you change memory available for data storage settings in R using OSX command line?

Tags: r

I'm very new to R and I'm having trouble changing the memory available for data storage setting "--max-ppsize".  From reading other posts, the error that resulted from running a line of my code (Error: protect(): protection stack overflow) indicates that I should change this to the maximum allowed value (--max-ppsize = 500000) using command line.  This threw an error because I'm trying to run the Rtsne package on a data set that is very large.  I don't fully understand how to run command line for R in OSX terminal.  I can launch R in terminal, but from there I'm not exactly sure what to do.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: See [ask]. You should [edit] this question so it is clear what you want to do, what you tried, and what results you get. Format things to make it easy to read. Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

So this ended up being a fairly simple fix with a fresh brain the next day.  I didn't end up changing the --max-ppsize.  I read another post's comments section and saw that I needed to use a data matrix (used data.matrix to change my data frame to a matrix) for the function I was trying to run.  Hope this helps someone else out.